# Overclocking monitor on Nvidia card: Override mode validation

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xrandr

I'm trying to achieve a 100 Hz refresh rate on my QNIX 2710 monitor, by overclocking from the original 60 Hz. I am running a Nvidia GTX 1070, which I was able to overclock to 110 Hz on Windows.

However, on Ubuntu I am not able to overclock the monitor at all. [This older blogpost](https://blog.patshead.com/2014/12/overclocking-my-qnix-qx2710-monitors-with-linux-and-xorg.html) describes how this was achieved with a Nvidia 970, but my monitor gets corrupt when running the neccessary `Option "UseEDID" "False"` and `Option "ModeValidation" "NoEDIDModes"`. Without these options, I can produce a custom `ModeLine`, but only for 60 Hz and below. When generating anything above this, the log file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` tells me that it is not a valid mode and it goes back to the default.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with the 455 driver from Nvidia.

I have also tried to achieve a overclock by Compizconfig Settings Manager by shutting off the detect refresh rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not used the `ModeValidation` options `AllowNonEdidModes` and `NoEdidMaxPClkCheck`, that Artem mentioned in his post. This along with the options from the blogpost, except those who was non-working for me, I made it work.

My own modelines where now accepted, but did not load on reboot. Hence I made a script

```
#!bin/bash
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 100.00
```

that I linked to `/etc/profile`, which then activates my modeline for 2560x1440 with 100 Hz framerate every time I log in.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/98-monitor.conf
Section "Screen"
    Option         "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes,NoEdidMaxPClkCheck,NoMaxPClkCheck"
    Monitor        "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Screen"
    Device         "Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor"
    HorizSync       30-83
    VertRefresh     56-75
EndSection

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-nvidia.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Videocard0"
    BusID       "PCI:7:0:0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA"
    BoardName   "NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti] (rev a1)"
    Option      "Coolbits" "28"
    Option      "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option      "UseEDIDFreqs" "Off"
    Option      "UseNvKmsCompositionPipeline" "Off"
EndSection
```

and https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/monitor_overclock

If it works under Windows for you, download [softMCCS](https://www.entechtaiwan.com/lib/softmccs.shtm) and copy your modeline from Windows.

Comment: The problem was not that I couldn't produce a working modeline. It was rather that it would not accept them for some reason. Your answer did however provide me with `Edid`-options I didn't know about, which turned out to help me.